# Como inserir dados (cadastro) no SQLite?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, eclipse, inserir

Olá, minha conexão com o SQLite está da seguinte forma:

```
Connection connection = null;

        try
          {
             // create a database connection
             connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:database.db");

             Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
             statement.setQueryTimeout(30);  // set timeout to 30 sec.

             statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name STRING, address STRING, telephone STRING, celphone STRING, email STRING, cpf STRING, password STRING)");   


          }
        catch(SQLException e){  System.err.println(e.getMessage()); }     

    }
```

Essa conexão está correta? Gostaria de saber também como faço para inserir dados no SQLite. Preciso inserir dados no SQLite para fazer cadastros no programa. O programa é para Desktop e não para Android. Estou usando o Eclipse.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Como está utilizando JDBC com nao muda muita coisa referente a outros bancos somente alguns parametros de conexao.

Exemplo de conexao com SQLite:

```
private Connection connect() {
    // SQLite connection string
    String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C://sqlite/db/test.db";
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
}
```

Após conectado é só seguir os mesmos passos de JDBC para fazer uma inserçao,
Exemplo:

```
public void insert(String column1, double column2) {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO teste(column1,column2) VALUES(?,?)";

        try (Connection conn = this.connect();
                PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            pstmt.setString(1, column1);
            pstmt.setString(2, column2);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```